# How to call the React Class in different "<script> tag"?

Tags: reactjs

### Environment

- HTML generator: **Pug (Jade)**
- ES6 transpiler: **Babel**

---

### Description

There is a component named `componentA` in `componentA.jsx`. In this script, it will render in the same time.

In `componentA.jsx` :

```
let ComponentA = React.createClass({
    render: function () { ... }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <ComponentA />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

In `index.pug` :

```
extends ./template.pug

block content
    div#container

    script(type='text/babel')
        include ./components/building.jsx
```

---

### Target / Goal

Remove the `ReactDOM.render` in `componentA.jsx`. Then I can use the `ComponentA` in others `<script> tag`, like code below. I want to move the action of rendering to other position.

In the new `componentA.jsx` :

```
let ComponentA = React.createClass({
    render: function () { ... }
});
```

In the new `index.pug` :

```
extends ./template.pug

block content
    div#container

    script(type='text/babel')
        include ./components/building.jsx

    script(type='text/babel').
        ReactDOM.render(
            <ComponentA />,
            document.getElementById('container')
        );
```

---

### Problem

Will get the error message in browser.

`ReferenceError: ComponentA is not defined`

Comment: Importing your componentA.jsx in index.pug and exporting componentA from componentA.jsx should work. `module.exports = ComponentA`

Comment: You either need to bundle (webpack or browserify), or you need to make `ComponentA` available globally.  using `let` will not scope it globally.  You will have to assign it to `window` or something similar.